# Webform Layout: Table or something else

Tags: css, layout, webforms, xhtml, html-table

I have to create a webform that looks something like this

```
column   column  -   column   column      column column   -   column column
label:   input   -   label:   input 
label:   input   -   label:   input   -   label: input
label:   input   -   label:   input
label:   input
label:   input   -   label:   input
label:   input   -   label:   input   -   label: input   -    input: label
```

etc..

Now what would be the best way to go about doing this?
I've been trying ways to accomplish with css but I've failed over and over again.

Should I just go ahead and use tables for this or is there a simple way to do this with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .column {
      width: 200px;
      float: left;
    }

    .column label {
      clear: both;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      text-align: right;
      width: 75px;
    }

    .column input {
      float: left;
      width: 100px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="column">
    <label>Label 1:</label> <input type="text" />
    <label>Label 2:</label> <input type="text" />
    <label>Label 3:</label> <input type="text" />
    <label>Label 4:</label> <input type="text" />
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <label>Label 5:</label> <input type="text" />
    <label>Label 6:</label> <input type="text" />
    <label>Label 7:</label> <input type="text" />
    <label>Label 8:</label> <input type="text" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you like that, you might consider using fieldsets instead of divs for the columns.  They style nicely and are more semantic.  Either way works well though.

Comment: Does this method work with anything but the simplest of forms?

Comment: You need more styling rules for larger forms, but this approach does work, yes.  In particular, fieldset elements are great for breaking large forms down into smaller, approachable problems.  It *seems* easier to fit fieldset blocks together than it does dozens of form elements.

Answer (score 4):

Just do it with tables. Tables are fine for tabular data, like stuff with columns and rows... like in your case!

Comment: here here.  In the wild world of HTML and CSS, do whatever looks right in the end, it all turns into a hack in the end ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did your formatting for the example not take? If you just want a label, input control, and a space, just add the controls to the page with no formatting whatsoever. HTML will lay out that way.

However, I assume you want some kind of columns. You have several possibilities. The most inflexible is absolutely positioning the controls (markup).

You could use tables, which would be the most straight-forward. However, purists would argue that tables are for data, not layout.

You could also left float a series of DIVs to represent columns: one column for a label, one for an input, a third for labels, a fourth for input, etc.

EDIT: If you aren't worried about labels lining up vertically with labels and inputs lining up vertically with inputs, just put one label + input pair in each column, whichever method above you choose.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example of the left float divs?
I've tried messing with floats and some stuff works in firefox, and chrome while others don't.

Thanks though!

Comment: <div style="float:left;width:100px;">Column1</div><div style="float:left;width:100px;">Column2</div> ... etc.